# Issue in access array Index by concatenating two string variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access an array index by concatenating two string variables.
Suppose there is :

```
$val1 = 2;
$val2 = 12;
$val3 = 1012;
```

I'm running a loop here to calculate all string lengths of the variables mentioned above and also accessing those variable indexes.

Following is my PHP code:

```
$val1 = 2;
$val2 = 12;
$val3 = 1012;
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    $count = 0;
    $valLength = strlen($val . $i);  // this gives me $val1 Length i.e "1"
    echo $valLength;exit;
    for($j=0; $j<$valLength; $j++){
        if($valLength==1){
            $count = "";
            echo $count; echo $val . $i[$j];exit; // This is where the problem is  echoes nothing 
            continue;
        }

        if($val . $i[$j]==0){$count = "";}
        if($val . $i % $val . $i[$j] == 0){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo $count."\n";
}
```

As you can see I cant access indexes of variables using this `$val . $i[$j]`
Is there any other way around to access it, or my concatenation syntax is not proper, Please suggest.

Comment: `$i` is not an array; hence there is no such thing as `$i[$j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $valLength = strlen($val . $i);  // this gives me $val1 Length i.e "1"
> ```

No, it does not. What this does is concatenate the value of `$val` (which does not exist and is `null`, activate your error reporting to see a notice pop up) and `$i` (which is `1`). The result of `null . 1` is the string `"1"`. The `strlen` of `"1"` is `1`.

There are many possible ways to make such [*variable variables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) work, but long story short: *use an array!*

```
$vals = array(
    1 => 2,
    2 => 12,
    3 => 1012
);

for ($i ..) {
    $vals[$i]
}

// or even:

foreach ($vals as $key => $value) ..
```

Comment: You almost got me in the first line before I read `no, it does not` :)

Comment: Quotes with code are unfortunately hardly distinguishable from just code... :o)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to get is variable variable.

```
echo ${"val{$i}"}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/XN4AN2cq)

Comment: I had even tried that, but how will you access an index in this case using the same syntax ?